# Where is the proper place to add a method to handle SQL Connection String in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a set of many databases that follow the same schema and I've abstracted the pertinent tables in the Model layer of the application. I'm using SQLConnections to handle connecting to the database and Data Adapters and Data Tables to store and move the information back to and through the controllers etc. The code below is what I am currently using, which is working fine for now:

```
using (SqlConnection con =    
    new SqlConnection(
    "server=MyServersIp\\NameofInstance; " +
    "initial catalog=thisisvariable;" +
    "user id=username;" +
    "password=password123;")) { /* Stuff happening here */ }
```

What I would like to be using is something more like this here:

```
using (SqlConnection con =    
    new SqlConnection(getConnectionString("databaseIdentifier")) 
    { 
        /* Stuff  still happening here */ 
    }
```

So I'm looking for the right place to put my method:

```
public string getConnectionString(string databaseIdentifier)
{ 
    String theConnectionStringIneed = "appropriateConnectionString"
    return theConnectionStringIneed; 
}
```

I am very new to MVC and Web API in terms of structure etc, and I want to make sure I'm following best practices.

My question is where in the standard structure should such a method go? I want it to be accessible from wherever in the hopes of keeping the whole Connection String process DRY, but I also need it to be somewhat dynamic (definite output based on database identifier input)

It seems like a simple enough question, but all I can find after some dedicated searching is examples on how to use Entity Framework or folks generating databases from a model, etc, not using Connection strings.

Please advise, and thank you as always SO community.

Comment: Added a little sidenote about 'code first' to my answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is meant to answer your more general question of "My question is where in the standard structure should such a method go? " and just expands on it a little with some architectural thoughts...

Not sure if you're already doing so, though I would put your database tasks - as in all your CRUD and connection stuff - into a project of it's own - Data Access layer in this case.. Keep this project separate from your models. - This kind of directly answers your initial question "where should it go..."

You can then add a reference to your model layer. (assuming you have all your models in a project on their own)

This keeps those 2 separate. Why? Well, one day you might decide to use Entity Framework, or some other means of communicating with your database. If that's the case then you only need to change your data access layer. And you can keep your models looking all shiny and new still.

If you want to really push the boat out then create another project that sits between your web site and the, now new, Data Access layer - call it services. This would be your middleman between your database and your website.

You would call this middleman service from your website controllers. The middleman service then runs off to the data access layer. That layer goes to the database, gets the data, populates the models and gives them back to your middleman. Your middleman now applies any business logic related to your site and also transforms your data models to things like view models (skinny versions of your models just for the website view you're showing) - this has the advantage of not sending big complex objects to your views for rendering. It also keeps business logic (which is more often than not related directly to the project calling the middleman) out of your data access and model layers.

Now things are nicely broken up and you can switch bits and bobs out as your requirements change.

So, in a total laymen term.. The workflow would be something like this:

- User clicks a link
- Web site controller gets hit to go fetch data...
- Controller asks the service middleman for the data, but the
  controller only wants a little bit of it, so asks for a small version
  (ViewModel)
- Service middleman says 'ok, gimme a sec..'
- Service middleman then runs over to the data access layer and says
  'Gimme this data' and asks for a full blown model (a row from the DB)
- The middleman then gets this back from the data access layer and says
  'hmm..the controller said he didn't need half of these properties..'
  so the middleman creates an instance of a ViewModel (that you
  defined, like a model).
- The middleman then populates this instance, the view model, with data
  from the model the data access layer gave it.
- The middleman might also do some other stuff, businessy-logic stuff..
- He then hands it back to the controller and says 'there you go
  govn'er '
- The controller then returns it in its action result.

And there is a fun lil way to explain it :D

**A little side note**

You mentioned that people generally seem to create a database from models - this is called Code First. You can also do Database First - exactly as it sounds..

I would, for this, recommend [Entity Framework Powertools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).  It has an awesome reverse-engineer tool which will build all of your models & relationships from your DB. Freakin awesome!

Comment: So what would the workflow be like? controller calls back to model which references the other project which calls the database and gets cruddy? I'm thinking separating the Data layer completely will allow me to change things up later, is this the only benefit or is there something security or performance wise i'm not thinking of. Thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: No mention of dependency injection, especially for a connection string?

Comment: @X3074861X - seriously? You'd take someone who seems pretty new to the idea of n-tiers and follow up the introduction to it with DI? - Besides, even with that you wouldn't need it. Simply have a base controller class that new's up your Data layer with the connection string - then you have single unit of work and a single place where the string is being set. no need for DI in there... Just a reason to use DI for the sake of using DI.

Comment: DI can be used for both the services layer and data layer. This provides a single location for initializing classes with connection strings, API creds, a logging construct, other static values, ect. It's a better design habit to get into, and it makes it easier to extend individual classes later on, rather than inheriting from a base class. DI also makes it easier to mock out separate components for unit and integration tests, too. I'm not saying anything is wrong with your answer, I'm just surprised you didn't mention DI as an architectural option, given it's many advantages.

Comment: Again, wasn't mentioned because the point of the post was to give an overview of a more standardized architecture, not a specific part of the architecture.

Answer (score 2):

If you put your connection strings in the web.config you can use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Comment: In web forms I usually handle a single database connection using ConfigurationManager and pulling the key, but in this case I have many databases connected to a single client, so I wanted something a bit different. Thanks for the response!

Comment: If you want to go the right way go with @Darren's answer (it's called n-layer if you want to look into it). If you're not going that far, I'd still have your method return the connection string from the web.config. Seems weird to not do it from the web.config.

Comment: I think you are correct, or rather I think I agree with you. The only thing that needs flexibility is the initial catalog once it's connected, so it stands to reason I can keep the rest of the string in web.config and just tack on the initial catalog portion of the string in the method. Your answers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a public static method to the WebApiConfig.cs file. This method takes in an identifier and spits back the connection string. There only needs to be the one, so this works alright. I'm moving on from this, but if there are comments for or against this method I'd love to hear it. I'm learning this stuff right now and Web API is a far cry from Web Forms. Thanks to all for your attention!

```
   public static string getConnectionString()
    {
        return "the connection string";
    }
```

EDIT: After reviewing comments in other answers, I've also added that I'm going to store the better part of the connection string in the web.config and only use the getConnectionString() method to pull from the ConfigurationManager and tack on the initial catalog, the only changing part of the connection string. Thanks all for your attention.

@Darren: I will also definitely look into N-Tier architecture as it looks like a pretty stable way of handling this, although I think it's outside of the scope of my intents as of right now. Thanks all for some excellent information on all sides.

Comment: You should have this static method return the connection string from the `web.config` like @Smith has suggested. It's not a good idea to hardcode connection string inside your C# code. What if the server name changes? Will you update this static method, rebuild and redeploy your code everything that happens?

Comment: That is an excellent point. The only thing that really needs to change is the initial catalog, so it stands to reason the rest should be kept in web.config. Thanks for the response!